# why body font size set before mouse click event?

Tags: javascript, closures

**Why body font size set before mouse click event? In the following code. Please explain.**

```
<body>
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<h1>some heading 1 text</h1>
<h2>some heading 2 text</h2>
<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = (function(size){
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
})(20);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Your code snippet is being evaluated on page load and returns `undefined` which has been assigned to `onclick` event. The `fontSize` property is changed before clicking any DOM element. From your example:

```
(function(size){
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
})(20);
```

**Longer asnwer with explanation:**

Let's see a quick example just to represent the evaluation order of the code:

```js
(function () {
  let returnValue = (function(size){
                       console.log(`Look, I'm evaluated`);
                    })(20);
  
  console.log('Return value of the code snippet', returnValue);
})();
```

To eliminate the issue you need to do the following:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function {
      document.body.style.fontSize = '20px';
   };
</script>
```

By doing this change, your code will run only when the user clicks the DOM element with the id of `size-12`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're executing the function *immediately* and setting the *result* of the function (which is `undefined`) to the `onclick` event.

If you just want to set the font size to 20 when you click the button, there's no need to wrap the function with a function call and overcomplicate things.  Just have a simple function and put the value in the one line of code:

```js
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '20px';
};
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<h1>some heading 1 text</h1>
<h2>some heading 2 text</h2>
<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because here you are using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) for your onclick handler. The function will be executed when the script loads and will return `undefined` to onclick property of your DOM element.

If all you want is to change font size on click, then you can do this without even having a script tag.

```
<a href="#" id="size-12" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize = '20px'">12</a>
```